# Error in executing compiler script for a custom MATLAB toolbox

Tags: compiler-errors, matlab, matlab-compiler

I want to provide a step by step troubleshooting to a problem I'm having.  I would like to use the toolbox found at http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~gbrown/fstoolbox/ for a variety of uses in my research being carried out in Matlab R2012a 32 bit.  Here is the error I see in Matlab when using the 'CompileFeat.m' script that must be called to compile the main toolbox functions designed in C.  Of course I copy the unzipped folder into my current working path, and add all folders to the current working path.

```
>> CompileFEAST

  C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'FSToolboxMex.c' not found. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in CompileFEAST (line 3)
mex -I../MIToolbox FSToolboxMex.c BetaGamma.c CMIM.c CondMI.c DISR.c ICAP.c JMI.c
mRMR_D.c ../MIToolbox/MutualInformation.c ../MIToolbox/Entropy.c
../MIToolbox/CalculateProbability.c ../MIToolbox/Arr
```

So after some digging on Google, I've seen many suggestions asking me to check if I have a compiler installed.  Please see code below:

```
>> mex -setup

Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012a/win32.html 

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012a\sys\lcc 
[2] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 

[0] None 

Compiler: 2

Please verify your choices: 

Compiler: Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 

Are these correct [y]/n? y

*************************************************************************** 
  Warning: MEX-files generated using Microsoft Windows Software Development  
           Kit (SDK) require that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 run-time  
           libraries be available on the computer they are run on. 
           If you plan to redistribute your MEX-files to other MATLAB 
           users, be sure that they have the run-time libraries. 
*************************************************************************** 


Trying to update options file: C:\Users\JQ\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2012a\mexopts.bat 
From template:              C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win32\mexopts\mssdk71opts.bat 

Done . . . 

************************************************************************** 
  Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB 
           variables with more than 2^32-1 elements.  In the near future 
           you will be required to update your code to utilize the new 
           API. You can find more information about this at: 
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsflnue-1.html 
           Building with the -largeArrayDims option enables the new API.
```

---

After completing this step I'd magically hope my next call to 'CompileFeast.m' would be successful.  Instead I receive:

```
>> CompileFEAST

  C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'FSToolboxMex.c' not found. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in CompileFEAST (line 3)
mex -I../MIToolbox FSToolboxMex.c BetaGamma.c CMIM.c CondMI.c DISR.c ICAP.c JMI.c
mRMR_D.c ../MIToolbox/MutualInformation.c ../MIToolbox/Entropy.c
../MIToolbox/CalculateProbability.c ../MIToolbox/Arr
```

Same issue again!  After further frustrations looking into the problem, one suggests using the **dir** function to see if the file is even in the directory (which it is not), see below:

```
>> dir 'CompileFEAST.m'
CompileFEAST.m not found.
```

To make sure I can see other files in my Matlab path, I check another function to see if its in the directory:

```
>> dir 'hurst.m'

hurst.m
```

As you can see this file is found in the directory.  I simply provided the same procedure as adding the above toolbox to my Matlab working path, all I do is copy the file into the working path and add files or subfolders to the path.

Does anyone notice where I am going wrong?  I am not very inclined at solving such problems, I more or less using Matlab as an on-the-go model building platform to understand algorithms.

I look forward to any comments.

Cheers,
J

Comment: MATLAB is finding CompileFEAST.m correctly. That is not the problem. It is not finding FSToolboxMex.c

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Navan!  As @am304 asks below, how do I check which directory FSToolboxMex.c is in?  How do I check what my current directory is?  I apologize for my basic question, a lot of this lingo is new to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your current directory (pwd) is wrong.

Try:

```
cd('E:\School\hidethis\hidethis\MATLAB work\FEAST\FEAST\FSToolbox')
CompileFEAST
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you may think that `FSToolboxMex.c` is in your MATLAB path, it appears that it isn't.

- What directory is `FSToolboxMex.c` in?
- What is your current directory (the one from which you run `CompileFEAST`)?
- What is your MATLAB path (use the `path` command)?
- What does `which -all FSToolboxMex.c` return?
- What does the code of `CompileFEAST` look like?

Comment: 1) How do I check which directory? 2) How do I check my current directory? 3) MATLABPATH and then a long list of which FEAST (the folder name of the toolbox) is at the top of the list 4) '>> which -all FSToolboxMex.c
E:\School\hidethis\hidethis\MATLAB work\FEAST\FEAST\FSToolbox\FSToolboxMex.c' 5) '%Compiles the FEAST Toolbox into a mex executable for use with MATLAB

mex -I../MIToolbox FSToolboxMex.c BetaGamma.c CMIM.c CondMI.c DISR.c ICAP.c JMI.c mRMR_D.c ../MIToolbox/MutualInformation.c ../MIToolbox/Entropy.c ../MIToolbox/CalculateProbability.c ../MIToolbox/ArrayOperations.c'

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'pwd' command showed me that I was not in the same path as `CompileFEAST.m`.  It was a simple as double-clicking and re-running the script.  This may be a embarrassing for me but at least I've learned my error!  Thanks all for the quick replies, greatly appreciated!

Best,
J